# Parse HTML from a Url to iOS swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

[image]
I have a Url that when I run it it displays html. I need to use url to display the contents in my iOS app. How do I do that? The examples I have found use WebKit, and I don't want to use webkit because I don't want the user to have the ability to use it as a website

Comment: You should be able to block navigation on a `WKWebView` and you don't need to show previous page button nor URL bar.

Comment: What actually you want to do? do you want to display HTML String in UILabel or you want to parse HTML and display it in other controls?

Comment: I have edited the question. When I use url with webkit I get the purple parts that are the header and footer. I don't want the purple parts displayed. I only want the yellow parts. @Larme

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UILabel` to display an attributed string parsed with your html string.

Here is the code in Swift 4

```
extension String {
    func toHtmlString() -> NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16, allowLossyConversion: false) else { return nil }
        guard let html = try? NSMutableAttributedString(
            data: data,
            options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html],
            documentAttributes: nil) else { return nil }
        return html
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, please check my image above. I only want the yellow parts displayed